# SQl select all if table exists

Tags: sql

I need to get all data from the table  if the table exists.

I tried this:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT *  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'2000064'))
```

But I do not get anything.

How can I get all data from a table if the table exists?

Comment: I think you just need to add the SELECT, as what you have written above is just the condition.

Comment: In what circumstance do you not know whether a table exists? Curious about your use case.

Comment: @GolezTrol the query will be used in a c# method so I do not wont to get back errors but only data if the table exists

Comment: I assume you can catch those errors in C# too (well, I *know* you can). But still, in what case would a table not exist? Is that a situation you need to catch in your application?

Comment: @GolezTrol I have a multilevel grid in which the additional levels are generated if any of the records has its own table. Not all records have the own table so I prefer to use "If Exists" in the onRowDataBound event like this: firstLevelGrid.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'{0}')) SELECT * from [{0}]", code));

Comment: @GolezTrol here you can find what I am trying to achieve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112897/trying-to-add-a-second-level-nested-table-without-sucess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'2000064'))
    SELECT * from [2000064]
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT *  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'2000064'))
    SELECT * FROM [200064]
```

This assumes you are using SQL Server, hence the square braces.