# Trying to add a second level nested table without sucess

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to learn how to add an additional nested table inside the firstLevelGrid but I am not succeding. Any help would be appreciated.
Particularly I am doing something wrong in managing the OnRowDataBound when I create the second level grid, both in the markup and the code behind.

This is the code I have that generate the grid and the first level. I have not added my attempts for the second level grid just to avoid to mess up the code.
It is not homework, I am not a professional coder and I am a selflearner.

```
<div>
        <asp:GridView ID="zeroLevelGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
            DataKeyNames="Code" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBoundZeroLevel">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                        <asp:Panel ID="firstLevelPanel" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                            <asp:GridView ID="firstLevelGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid">
                                <Columns>
<!-- Here is where I add the second level grid copying the entire block "TemplateFiled" of the firstLevelGrid and renaming it secondLevel...-->
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" />
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
                 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" />
                 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

and my c# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        zeroLevelGrid.DataSource = GetData("select top 10 * from Table_xx");//top10 only for test purposes
        zeroLevelGrid.DataBind();
    }
}

private static DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void OnRowDataBoundZeroLevel(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string code = zeroLevelGrid.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        GridView firstLevelGrid = e.Row.FindControl("firstLevelGrid") as GridView;
        firstLevelGrid.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'{0}')) SELECT * from [{0}]", code));
        firstLevelGrid.DataBind();
    }
  }
  //here is where I add an OnRowDataBound event copying the above one as OnRowDataBoundFirstLevel
  //but then I get lost...
}
```

I would be glad if someone could indicate me how to add an additional level of nested grid inside the firstLevelGrid identical to it. I would be happy to offer a bounty to get this right but unfortunatelly I do not have enough rep yet. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similart to your firstLevelGrid, you have to declare the third level grid inside the firstLevelGrid as a template column

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="secondLevelGrid"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid">
                    <Columns>
                        <%--Your columns go here--%>
                        </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then handle OnRowDataBound event for the firstLevelGrid

```
OnRowDataBound="firstLevelGrid_OnRowDataBound"
```

In the RowDataBound event you can get the grid view, data key and bind the child grid

```
protected void firstLevelGrid_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridView firstLevelGrid = e.Row.NamingContainer as GridView;
        string code = firstLevelGrid.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        GridView secondLevelGridView = e.Row.FindControl("secondLevelGrid") as GridView;
        secondLevelGridView.DataSource = //GetData
        secondLevelGridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Kiran, thanks a lot. I followed your sample above. I got an error that I fixed adding the DataKeyNames="Code" under the firstLevelGrid. You answerd my question.I understood the òogic of this. Thanks again.