# sql: select if table exists

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2, cockroachdb

I'm trying to select all from db.table if db.table exists. I've tried if, exists, etc. and none works. What's the best way to do this? I'm using cockroachdb and psycopg2. Didn't find an existing answer (most are quite old) 
that I could use. For example, this one didn't work me: [SQl select all if table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087283/sql-select-all-if-table-exists)

I tried the following per Tim's suggestion, which doesn't seem to work. However, the db.table exists.

```
 select exists (select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'table')                                                                          ;
  exists  
+--------+
  false   
(1 row)

Time: 6.848579ms

select exists (select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'db.table')                                                                      ;
  exists  
+--------+
  false   
(1 row)

Time: 5.958707ms
```

Comment: What is your actual underlying SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.)?  Every database has its own syntax for checking for this.

Comment: psycopg2 (Postgres), as the tag indicates

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that `psycopg2` is Postgres, I'll try to keep that in mind for next time!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks. I tried it and it doesn't seem to work for me. Could you pls take a look at the update above?

Comment: Most likely your actual table name is not `table`.  When you do `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables`, do you see your table anywhere?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are absolutely correct. My table is not listed there. However, when do select * from my table, I can see it. Why is that?

Comment: That shouldn't be happening, and the only thing which comes to mind is that maybe you are on the wrong database at the moment.  So, you should confirm you are using the correct database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You were correct, I was in the wrong database. To make sure this works even when connecting from another db, I can just add the db_name in front of information_schema.tables, right? Basically like this: select exists (select 1 from db.information_schema.tables where table_name = 'table')

Comment: That sounds about right, but can't you test this yourself?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah I did that. What I meant to suggest was, it's always a good thing to specify the db to be safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may handle this in two steps.  First, check if the table exists in your Postgres database, and, if so, then select all records:

```
sql = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = %s"
cur.execute(sql, ('your_table',))
if cur.fetchone()[0]:
    sql_all = "SELECT * FROM your_table"
    cur = connection.cursor()    # get a new cursor
    cur.execute(sql_all)
    # process result set etc.
```